# xCode show app users on inapp map services

Tags: ios, c, swift, maps, xcode6

I've recently started to learn how to develop with Xcode and I have a question about the map and gps services.

Does anyone know what kind of resources I would have to use if I wanted to have a map in my app that shows the location of other people who use the app?

I have a general idea that each person would need an account for my app,

But would I have to put everyone's gps coordinates onto a server (SQLite?) and then constantly make the app fetch this information?

I am aiming for a similar concept that the app Called "Uber" uses where you can see taxi drivers around you and they are moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you will probably need to store each user's GPS coordinates somewhere in a database. Then you can draw annotations on Apple's map view or on a map view that Google provides in their iOS helper once you fetch information from the database. I would not constantly update the user's map though.  You should update it every 5 minutes, or when the user asks for it to be refreshed either through a button or some other form. Also if you plan to find the nearest user to them from the database I recommend using the Haversine Forumula (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).